# Set future date as default value in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, date, sequelize.js

I need orientation with a requirement. I'm working on a API Express with Sequelize ORM for work in MySQL. In a table I need to set a column with a `start_date` with the current date as the default value, and a `expiration_date`, which should be one year after the `start_date`.

```
startDate: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    field: 'start_date',
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
},
expirationDate: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    field: 'expiration_date',
    defaultValue: //365 days after startDate
}
```

Comment: did the answer work with you ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't set a default value for `expirationDate`, but when you create an object with startDate, you can:

```
Object.expirationDate = Date.now() + 31536000000 // after 365 day
```

365 day * 24 hour * 60 minute * 60 second * 1000 millisecond = 31536000000 millisecond